# Team Foundation Server - Local Service Account missing dnx - builds fail? How to fix

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

Trying to build a simple web project (MVC 5) that runs fine from Visual Studio 2015, but fails when I build it from team foundation server 2015 using TFSBUILD (not using xaml) ...both vs and tfs are on the same machine, Windows 2012 Enterprise, VS 2015, using the local service account for TF.

It seems the local service account is missing the dnx resources so fails - and when I try to add them via a script (see answer below for the script) it gets further in the process but blows up.

**UPDATE:** Seems like it can't find the global.json file so is using the latest version (update2).

> **WARNING: Unable to locate global.json to determine using 'latest' Determining latest version** 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2' is
>   already installed in
>   C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2.

But it subsequently bombs because it's actually looking for update1

> Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-**update1** in the
>   folder: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService.dnx\runtimes

I have changed the build configuration settings, replaced any reference of update1 to update2 in all files, and still it wants update1.

**So my question is, what do I have to do to either 1. reconfigure TFS, or 2.  Get the resources into the path of the local system account.**

During the build I get the following:

---

> GetRuntimeToolingPathTarget: Cannot find DNX runtime
>   dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 in the folder:
>   C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService.dnx\runtime
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(126,5):
>   Error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output
>   window for more details.
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(126,5):
>   error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output
>   window for more details.
>   [C:\TfsData\Agents\Agent-DESKTOP-U7761A8_work\2\s\MvcMovie\src\MvcMovie\MvcMovie.xproj]

---

Basically it's complaining it cant find the dnx libraries in the folder  C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService.dnx\runtime .  The local service profile does not have the libraries installed in C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService.dnx\runtime.

I can install these libraries from the command line, but it only sticks those in *my* local user account, even with -global etc..And that the build in TFS still fails.

Results of DMVM LIST:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          win             default
       1.0.0-rc1-update2 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update2 coreclr x86          win
```

I used a powershell script that installed the libraries into the local service account folders, and after that the build go further but then bombed out - seemed there were library conflicts:

> 2016-04-06T23:04:56.0966631Z          Building WebApplication4 for
>   DNX,Version=v4.5.1 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Using
>   Project dependency WebApplication4 1.0.0 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z 
>   Source:
>   C:\TfsData\Agents\Agent-DESKTOP-U7761A8_work\3\s\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.json
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z 
>   Unable to resolve dependency EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
>   7.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet 1.0.0-rc1
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity 7.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 3.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z
>   Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
>   6.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5039430Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5498358Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions
>   1.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5654146Z            Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
>   1.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5654146Z            Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
>   1.0.0-rc1-final 2016-04-06T23:04:56.5966887Z            Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5966887Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.5966887Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 1.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z            Unable to resolve dependency
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader 14.0.0-rc1-final
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z            Using Assembly dependency
>   fx/mscorlib 4.0.0 2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z              Source:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z            Using Assembly dependency
>   fx/System 4.0.0 2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z              Source:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z            Using Assembly dependency
>   fx/System.Core 4.0.0 2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z              Source:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z            Using Assembly dependency
>   fx/Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0 2016-04-06T23:04:56.6122983Z
>   Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>   2016-04-06T23:04:56.8622811Z
>
> ### [error]C:\TfsData\Agents\Agent-DESKTOP-U7761A8_work\3\s\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.lock.json(1,0):
>
> Error NU1009: The expected lock file doesn't exist. Please run "dnu
>   restore" to generate a new lock file. 2016-04-06T23:04:56.8622811Z

Comment: Which build system are you using? XAML or vNext?

Comment: I'm using  TFBuild

Answer (score 0):

For your question:

**1. Reconfigure TFS**

You can configure your build service to run with the account that dnx has been installed. I assume you are using XAML build system, you can change it from here:
[image]

**2. Get the resources into the path of the local system account.**

According to the error message you get after installing dnx into local service account, the dun packages weren't restored before build. So you need to add some code in your powershell script to perform a dun restore for "project.json" file to restore the dun packages.

Following is a powershell sample provided by Microsoft to install dnx runtime and restore dun packages:

```
# bootstrap DNVM into this session.
&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}

# load up the global.json so we can find the DNX version
$globalJson = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\global.json -Raw -ErrorAction Ignore | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Ignore

if($globalJson)
{
    $dnxVersion = $globalJson.sdk.version
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "Unable to locate global.json to determine using 'latest'"
    $dnxVersion = "latest"
}

# install DNX
# only installs the default (x86, clr) runtime of the framework.
# If you need additional architectures or runtimes you should add additional calls
# ex: & $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -r coreclr
& $env:USERPROFILE\.dnx\bin\dnvm install $dnxVersion -Persistent

 # run DNU restore on all project.json files in the src folder including 2>1 to redirect stderr to stdout for badly behaved tools
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object { & dnu restore $_.FullName 2>1 }
```

Comment: I get this error and then  "Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1" -

**WARNING: Unable to locate global.json to determine using 'latest'
Determining latest version**
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-**update2** from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Installing to C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2
Adding C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin to process PATH
Adding C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin to user PATH

Comment: with the script you pointed out,  I get that error - I've changed every and all references from update1 to update to in my files to no avail..   It's defaulting to the latest version.. is there somewhere I can force it to use update2?  right now it's listed as the default when I do a dnvm list under my login (not the local service account the build uses)

Comment: @RubenObregon The powershell script read the global.json file in your project to determine which dnx version to install for your project. You need to update the script to point it to the path of your global.json file.